# How can I set text align right in the column on the laravel Excel maatwebsite?

Tags: excel, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-excel

I get reference from here : https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.0/getting-started/

I have been looking for how to set the text align right, but I did not find it in the documentation

My script export like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Exports;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
class InvoiceExport implements FromView
{
    use Exportable;
    public function view(): View
    {
        $data = Invoice::get();
        return view('exports.item', [
            'data' => $data
        ]);
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

**Update**

I find a solution, but it's not perfect

```
public function registerEvents(): array
{
    return [
        AfterSheet::class    => function(AfterSheet $event) {
            $event->sheet->styleCells(
                'C2:C1000',
                [
                    'alignment' => [
                        'horizontal' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT,
                    ],
                ]
            );
        },
    ];
}
```

It works. But my record is dynamic. It can be 1000 records. it can be 10000 records

In my script above, it just block from C2 to C1000. I want to set all records in column C

How can I do it?

Comment: Maybe this answers your question, see: https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/1597

Comment: @Oluwatobi Samuel Omisakin I using laravel excel maatwebsite version 3. No version 2

Comment: Unfortunately I am not sure 3.0 has that feature but I may be wrong. You can also check some familiar issues on Github: https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues?q=is%3Aissue+align+is%3Aclosed

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin I have seen that, but I did not find a solution

Comment: In your `exports.item` blade file, just use `<td style="text-align: right;">...</td>` (or `<td align="right"...`) where you want right-aligned Excel cells. This is for version 2.1, but I'm sure the logic still applies: https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/2.1/blade/styling.html#using-html-attributes

Comment: @Tim Lewis I had try it. But it does not work in the version 3

Comment: I had update my question. Please look at that

Comment: @SuccessMan try this https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/79

Comment: @RaheelAslam It works. But as I said in my question. My record is dinamyc. It can be 1000 records. it can be 10000 records. So I want to block all record in the column C

Comment: try to select entire column by `'C:C'`.

Comment: @Mahbub It does not work

Comment: I'm using Laravel Excel 3.1.32, and `$event->sheet->styleCells()` method isn't available...

Answer (score 3):

For Laravel Excel 3.1.12, we could use `registerEvents` and `Macro` :

```php
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Sheet;

...

    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            // array callable, refering to a static method.
            AfterSheet::class => [self::class, 'afterSheet'],
        ];
    }

    public static function afterSheet(AfterSheet $event)
    {
        Sheet::macro('styleCells', function (Sheet $sheet, string $cellRange, array $style) {
            $sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->applyFromArray($style);
        });

        $event->sheet->styleCells('D:D', [
            'alignment' => [
                'horizontal' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT,
            ],
        ]);
    }

...
```

Comment: Works for me :). Just add ```use Maatwebsite\Excel\Sheet;```

Answer (score 2):

Just use C:C which will select the entire column:

```
'C:C',
[
    'alignment' => [
        'horizontal' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT,
    ],
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code works for me

```
 $event->sheet->getStyle('A1:B48')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - First You Add This On The Top:

> AfterSheet

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\{
        BeforeExport,
        AfterSheet
};
```

2 - Second implements WithEvents With YourClass

> WithEvents

```
class YourClass implements WithEvents {
```

3 - Third Add This On Body Of Class:

> getAlignment

```
    public function registerEvents(): array
        {
            return [
                AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) {
                  // multi cols
                  $event->sheet->getStyle('A:B')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
                  // single col
                  $event->sheet->getStyle('D')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
                },
            ];
        }
```