# Error while applying color to excel cell in laravel excel export

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel, argb

I am exporting excel for bulk upload in PHP laravel.
I am applying color to cell applying the following method:-

```
    public function styles(Worksheet $sheet)
    {
        return [
            'A1'  => [
                'fill' => [
                    'fillType' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                    'startColor' => [
                        'rgb' => '#fa7b3e'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
```

when I open exported excel in google sheet it worked fine but when opened in Microsoft office it shows only black color where this color applied.

when I apply `'argb' => 'FFFF0000'` instead of `'rgb' => '#fa7b3e'` it is working fine in Microsoft office.

please, give me some link or solution to this problem. I can't able to find argb color code like this `FFFF0000` online. I found this rgba code `rgba(250, 123, 62, 1)`

Comment: try with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57384209/how-to-set-background-color-for-row-in-laravel-excel

Answer (score -1):

You cant apply hex to rgb, you need to convert it first.

you can use any colorpicker and configure it for rgb or use [w3schools script](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_converter.asp)

Here is another answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40280985/477902